# How to enable HUD in KDE Plasma to search menu items?

Tags: kde, search, hud, kde5

I was a unity user back when the Unity Desktop Environment was still a thing in Ubuntu. I liked the feature that when I press the alt key by itself, I could get a search bar used to search in the application menubar. This feature is called HUD (Head Up Display). I use the global menu widget under my KDE install, and I wonder if there is a way to search inside menu just like in Unity. 
Thanks for trying to help out.

Currently, my only way is to
`sudo apt install unity -y`, which is not an alternative.

Comment: The left windows (super) key opens a search bar in gnome

Comment: I am actually taking about Plasma, and about searching in menus. The gnome search doesn’t search in menu. Anyway, I really appreciate you for taking part of this question.

Comment: The Ubuntu Mate edition incorporated this feature (as an option). However, indeed, also Plasma should support a HUD function.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You will need to have either global menu widget enabled, or have app menu button in the titlebar.

- To install the dependencies, run

```
sudo apt install rofi python3 python3-dbus python3-setproctitle python3-xlib gir1.2-gtk-3.0
sudo apt install appmenu-gtk2-module appmenu-gtk3-module
```

- Download the source code:

```
git clone https://github.com/Zren/plasma-hud
cd plasma-hud
```

- Use the following commands to install the files

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/plasma-hud
sudo cp usr/lib/plasma-hud/plasma-hud /usr/lib/plasma-hud/
sudo mkdir -p /etc/xdg/autostart
sudo cp etc/xdg/autostart/plasma-hud.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/
```

- Log out and log in.
- Run the following two commands one by one to bind the `Alt` keys to HUD.

```
kwriteconfig5 --file ~/.config/kwinrc --group ModifierOnlyShortcuts --key Alt "com.github.zren.PlasmaHUD,/PlasmaHUD,com.github.zren.PlasmaHUD,toggleHUD"
qdbus org.kde.KWin /KWin reconfigure
```

This answer was based on the README of [this](https://github.com/Zren/plasma-hud/) project.

Comment: tested and works a treat in kubuntu 19.10, please note that appmenu-qt package is not available but it does not seem to be required

Comment: @castaway That's great. appmenu-qt was available in 18.04.  I will open a github issue to let the developers know.

Comment: The last commands to bind the shortcut seem to only intermittently work for me.