# Is there any way in which I can get back the global menu bar in ubuntu

Tags: globalmenu

Im looking for global menu bar in ubuntu. I have fully customized ubuntu to look like macOS but  the only thing missing is a global menu bar [like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN7JX.jpg)

I have tried everything like fildem and gnome hud menu. They dont work. Is there a way to get back the old menu bar. Because I want to give the useless space on the top some functionality so yea.

Comment: For HUD see https://askubuntu.com/a/1348526/66509 .

Answer (score 2):

Currently the easiest and best performing option would be to switch to the Mate desktop. The Mate desktop continues the global menu that was developed for Unity. It is turned on with the "Mutiny" layout, but you can, of course, also enable it in other layouts.

Alternatively, you could still install the Unity desktop.

The global menu works well in many applications, but not all. That is because in Linux, many different graphical toolkits exist to develop programs, each requiring different ways to extract the menu where it is possible at all.